# Uploading and Downloading in Visual Studio vs. Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When you create code in Visual Studio, it runs from a temp directory. But at a hosting provider (one that specifically hosts ASP.NET sites), it will be in a different directory (typically an app server virtual folder with IIS). I need to have uploaded files in a directory the IIS web server can find them, so the use case below will work.

Q: How can I define my links in MVC Controllers/Views so that they work both in development as well as in production (upload & download)?

*Use Case*: My app needs to allow a file to be uploaded (still don't know where on dev box to upload to), and then via a link on another page download that same file.

Comment: Use `Server.MapPath()` to create and get the relative or virtual path of your folders/files

Comment: Side note: make sure you have enough budget to pay for hosting that allows to run code as full trust...

Answer (score 0):

In case you're in need of a more detailed answer I'll give you some hints and hopefully this will get you on the right track.

1. Define a contract so you can abstract any concrete file provider implementation in order to minimize the impact and modifications to your code if you need to change the underlying file storage later. For instance if you go to Azure in a future version you can implement an AzureFileProvider and store your file using Blobs.

   ```
   public interface IFileProvider
   {
       UploadResult UploadFile(byte[] fileContent, string fileName);
       DownloadResult DownloadFile(int fileId);
   }
   ```

Implement your interface for a file system-based file provider:

```
public class FileSystemFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    public FileSystemFileProvider(string absouteBasePath)
    {
        //Check if absoluteBasPath exists and create the directory if it doesn't.
        if (!Directory.Exists(absouteBasePath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(absouteBasePath);
    }

    public UploadResult UploadFile(byte[] fileContent, string fileName)
    {
        //TODO: Your upload file implementation here
    }

    public DownloadResult DownloadFile(int fileId)
    {
        //TODO Your download file implementation here
    }
}
```

You can adjust your contract according to your needs. Here in this sample UploadResult and DownloadResult are simple classes to retrieve the result of the operations. For example this could be a definition for DownloadResult:

```
public class DownloadResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
    public string DownloadName { get; set; }
    public string SizeInBytes { get; set; }
    //... any other useful properties
}
```

2. In your StartupAuth.cs or Global.asax (the place where your bootstrapper code runs, initialize the file provider with your concrete implementation. This approach works better with an IoC container in place. You can use [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/), [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) or any other you like, but please do your self a favor and use one.

   ```
   //read the base path from web.config so you may adjust it on production hosting provider without need to make and compile the app
   var fileBasePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileBasePath"];

   //get the path as an absolute file system path
   var absoluteBasePath = Server.MapPath(fileBasePath);

   //Initialize the file provider with the absolute path
   var fileProvider = new FileSystemFileProvider(absoluteBasePath);

   //TODO: Configure your IoC to return the fileProvider instance when an IFileProvider is requested.
   ```
3. As you see in step 2 I read an application setting value from the web.config file. This should be present on appSettings section in your configuration file.

   ```
   <appSettings>
     <add key="fileBasePath" value="~/FileStorage"/>
   </appSettings>
   ```
4. With all this in place you could inject your fileProvider to your controllers like this:

   ```
   public class UploadController : Controller
   {
       private readonly IFileProvider fileProvider;

       public UploadController(IFileProvider fileProvider)
       {
           this.fileProvider = fileProvider;
       }
   ```

And then you can use your provider on the relevant action when need it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(FileUploadModel model)
{
    //Validate
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Use your fileProvider here to upload the file
        var content = new byte[model.PostedFile.ContentLength];
        model.PostedFile.InputStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        var result = fileProvider.UploadFile(content, model.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            //TODO: Notify the user about operation success

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Upload");
        }
    }

    //
    return View(model);
}
```

Hope this helps!

PS: I don't know why code formatting is a little bit crazy.

Comment: Extra 4 space indent if in numbered list :)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Stephen.

Comment: @KarelTamayo This is a very interesting answer! This will take me time to digest. I was just looking for where to save uploaded files so they could be found by IIS in production, but I see so much iun your answer that I like, I want to investigate! Thank you!!!